# Laravel Cors Error during passport redirection

Tags: php, laravel, next.js, laravel-passport

I am getting this error during passport authorization code grant redirection.

Basically I am having a client application which is a next js application that is running on http://localhost:3005 and my callback url is http://localhost:3005/auth/callback

[image]

My authorization / resource (laravel) server runs on http://localhost:5001

What I did to initiate to authorization

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import qs from "qs";
export default function Home() {
  const redirect = () => {
    const queryString = {
      client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_REDIRECT,
      response_type: "code",
      scope: "seed_payment",
      prompt: "login",
    };
    return (window.location.href = `${
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_AUTH_SERVER
    }/oauth/authorize?${qs.stringify(queryString)}`);
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <button onClick={redirect}> Login</button>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above will prompt user to login but when it is about to redirect, it gets laravel cors error

[image]

This is the url it is redirected to

```
http://localhost:3005/auth/callback?code=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
```

[image]

I tried adding my application url in cors.php but it still shows error.

[image]

In case you need to see my Login Post route

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 */
public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();
  
    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: Please check the CORS pre-flight (Request Method: OPTIONS) request / response header in your developer console. Share them here if possible

Comment: Thank you for replying, now there is a different problem , I will close this

Comment: Hi @desh, I'm facing the same problem (actually I've a native application running, not a PA like you..). How did you solve it?

Comment: @Zoba82 sorry bro for the late reply, i cant recall what is the solution, i think it was something to do with Inertia's redirect to a third party page which was causing the error.